# How to implement listview with fragment, custom adapter, tabs and viewpager in android

Tags: android, android-listview, fragment, listadapter, android-listfragment

I'm trying to implement an activity with a viewpager and two tabs in order to allow swipe gestures between sections, each one containing a listview with a custom adapter which loads datas from an asynctask. I would like to show a loading spinner while loading data.

If we use a normal listview with a simple adapter it works. The problem arises when we introduce a custom adapter for the listviews. Eclipse returns the following error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at libraries.BoostAdapter.getCount(BoostAdapter.java:58)
>     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:466)
>        at kasuga.gamble.roma.LikeAttendList$AppSectionsPagerAdapter$LikeFragmentList.onActivityCreated(LikeAttendList.java:237)
>     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:891)
>     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
>     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
>   [...]

Any advice would be most welcome! Thank you.

- The activity (for simplicity's sake let's consider only one ListFragment)

  ```
    public class LikeAttendList extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener 
    {
     AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
     //ListView Adapter
     static BoostAdapter adapterLike;
     static BoostAdapter adapterAttend;
     ViewPager mViewPager;

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.attendlike);

      //Retrieve intent extras: event Id
      Intent i2 = getIntent(); 

      uid = i2.getExtras().getString("eventid");

      //Adapter creation
      Log.e("LikeAttend Report", "Entering LikeAttendList, eventID: " + uid);
      // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the two sections
      // of the app.
      mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

      // Set up the action bar.
      final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

      // Specify that the Home/Up button should not be enabled, since there is no hierarchical
      // parent.
      actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

      // Specify that we will be displaying tabs in the action bar.
      actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

      // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter and setting up a listener for when the
      // user swipes between sections.
      mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
      mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
      mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() 
      {
          @Override
          public void onPageSelected(int position) 
          {
              // When swiping between different app sections, select the corresponding tab.
              // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to     the
              // Tab.
              actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
          }
      });

      // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
      for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) 
      {
          // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter.
          // Also specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the
          // listener for when this tab is selected.
          actionBar.addTab(
                  actionBar.newTab()
                          .setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                          .setTabListener(this));
      }
    }

    /**
     * A FragmentPagerAdapter that returns a fragment corresponding to one of the primary
     * sections of the app.
     */
    public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
    {

      public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) 
      {
          super(fm);
      }

      @Override
      public Fragment getItem(int i) 
      {
          switch (i) 
          {
          case 0:
                  // The first section of the app shows all likes.
                  return new LikeFragmentList();

                 //The second should show all user who will attend the event
          default:
              // The other sections of the app are dummy placeholders.
              Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
              Bundle args = new Bundle();
              args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
              fragment.setArguments(args);
              return fragment;
          }
      }
      public static class LikeFragmentList extends ListFragment 
      {
          private ListView listv;
          private BoostAdapter adapter;

          @Override
          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
          {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                  //retrieves data from asyncTask
              LikeAttendList mc = new LikeAttendList();
              mc. new EventDataTask().execute(uid);
                  //Sets up the adapter 
              Activity ctx = this.getActivity();
              adapterLike = new BoostAdapter(ctx, userList);

          }

          @Override
          public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
          {

              View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.likelist, container, false);

              listv = (ListView) v1.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
              return v1;

          }

          @Override
          public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
          {
              super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
              //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,countries);

              listv.setAdapter(adapterLike);

              /* Trying to implement a cross fade transition, we should use an xml with the listview and the loading spinner, all advices
              //Cross Fade transition views
              // save the content
              mContentView = getView().findViewById(R.id.likelist);

              // save the loading spinner
              mLoadingView = getView().findViewById(R.id.loading_spinner);

              // remove content
              mContentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

              // save the animation duration
              mAnimationDuration = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_longAnimTime);
              */
          }
      }

      public String[] titles=
      {
         "Likes",
         "Attends"
      };

      @Override
      public int getCount() 
      {
          return titles.length;
      }

      @Override
      public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) 
      {
          return titles[position];
      }
    }

    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment 
    {
      public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
              Bundle savedInstanceState) 
      {
          View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_dummy, container, false);
          Bundle args = getArguments();
          ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
                  getString(R.string.dummy_section_text, args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
          return rootView;
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
    {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
    {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
     public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
    {

    }

    private class EventDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> 
    {
      //Returns a ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> with datas called userlist used to populate listview. cf: onCreate in LikeFragmentList()
       private View mContent;
   private View mSpinner;
   private int mDuration;

   public EventDataTask() 
   {

       eventsFunctions = new EventsFunctions();
   }

       protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... uid) 
       {
  Log.e("Social","List Requested: num item: " + max_item +" page number: " + current_page );
  // getting JSON string from URL
      current_page=1;
      String eventId=uid[0];
      return eventsFunctions.eventList(Integer.toString(current_page),Integer.toString(max_item),TAG_ACTIVITY, eventId );
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) 
   {
      // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
      //Log.e("All Socials list data Once: ", json.toString());

      userList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

  try 
      {
           // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
           String success = json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);
           if (success != null) 
           {
               if (Integer.parseInt(json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS)) != 0)
               {
                   JSONArray like = json.getJSONArray("likes");
                  for (int i = 0; i < like.length(); i++) 
                  {
                          JSONObject c = like.getJSONObject(i);

                          String name     = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                          String score    = c.getString(TAG_SCORE);
                          String photo    = c.getString(TAG_PHOTO);

                          // creating new HashMap
                          HashMap<String, String> firstItemMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                          // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                          firstItemMap.put(TAG_SCORE, score);
                          firstItemMap.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                          firstItemMap.put(TAG_PHOTO, photo);

                          // adding HashList to ArrayList 
                          userList.add(firstItemMap);

                   }

                           for (int j=0; j< userList.size(); j++ )
                      {
                          //Log.e("AllEvents Reporter", "Torneo numero: "+ j + " Nome: " + tornei.get(j).getName());
                          Log.e("Social Reporter", "utente numero: "+ j + " Nome: " + userList.get(j).get(TAG_NAME));
                      }
               }  
             }
      }
      catch (JSONException e) 
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  super.onPostExecute(json);
     }
    }
  }
  ```

---

-Custom BoostAdapter created:

```
    public class BoostAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
        private static String logo_path = "http://userk.servehttp.com/Gamble/Immagini/Pokeroom/All/";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PEOPLE = "people";
    private static final String TAG_UID = "uid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_RANKING = "ranking";
    private static final String TAG_PROFILEPICTURE = "photo";
    private static final String TAG_EVENTUID = "eventuid";

    EventsFunctions eventsFunctions;
    Bitmap bitmapLogo;
    Bitmap bit;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> people;
    private Activity context;

    public BoostAdapter() 
    {
        super();
    }

    public BoostAdapter(Activity ctx, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> persons) 
    {
        super();
        context = ctx;
        people = persons;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() 
    {
        return people.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return people.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }
    static class ViewHolder 
    {
        public TextView row_name;
        public TextView rankinglist;
        public ImageView image;
    }



    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)   
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            ViewHolder viewholder = new ViewHolder();
            viewholder.row_name= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.row_name);
            viewholder.rankinglist= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.rankinglist);
            viewholder.image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.row_icon);
            vi.setTag(viewholder);
        }

        //Log.e("BassAdapter Reporter","Checking infos retrivial: Received event: " + Integer.toString(position) + " of " +Integer.toString(tornei.size()) + 
        //      " Infos:\n Name: "+ tornei.get(position).get(TAG_NAME) + " logo: " +  tornei.get(position).get(TAG_LOGO) +" Gtd: " + tornei.get(position).get(TAG_GTD).length() +"Buyin: "+ tornei.get(position).get(TAG_BUYIN) + "  partecipanti " + tornei.get(position).get(TAG_PARTECIPANTI));  

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        holder.row_name.setText(people.get(position).get(TAG_NAME));
        holder.row_name.setMaxLines(1);
        holder.rankinglist.setText(people.get(position).get(TAG_RANKING));
        if (people.get(position).get(TAG_PROFILEPICTURE)!="")
        {
            String url2 = logo_path + people.get(position).get(TAG_PROFILEPICTURE);
            //Log.e(" Adapter report:", tornei.get(position).getName() + " and its image path is " + url2);
            Log.e("Adapter report:", "Item " + Integer.toString(position) + " of " +Integer.toString(people.size()));
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(url2, holder.image);
        }
        return vi;
    }
          }
```

---

These are the xml required:

- likelist

> ```
> <LinearLayout 
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:orientation="vertical" >
>
>     <ListView
>         android:id="@android:id/list"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"/>
>
>     <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/loading_spinner_like"
>         style="?android:progressBarStyleLarge"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_gravity="center" />
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

- attendlike.xml

  ```
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/pager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  ```
- attendlikelistitem

> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="50dp"
>     android:orientation="horizontal" 
>     android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
>
>   <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/row_icon"
>         android:layout_width="50dp"
>         android:layout_height="50dp"
>         android:padding="5dp"
>         android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:orientation="vertical"
>         android:baselineAligned="false"
>         android:paddingLeft="7dp"
>         android:paddingTop="5dp">
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/row_name"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>             android:text="@string/namelist"
>             android:textColor="#000000"
>             android:textSize="15sp"
>             android:ellipsize="marquee"
>           android:scrollHorizontally="true"
>             android:textStyle="bold"/> 
>
>         <LinearLayout 
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/ramkingList"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>                 android:text="@string/rankinglist"
>                 android:textColor="#000000"
>                 android:textSize="14sp" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/rankinglist"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>                 android:text="@string/rankingexample"
>                 android:textColor="#000000"
>                 android:textSize="14sp" />
>
>
>         </LinearLayout>
>     </LinearLayout>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Comment: userList is null .... AsyncTask.execute do not wait until job is done ...

Comment: ok that's the problem, I've already put the asynctask in the onCreate() method in LikeFragmentList class and then called `adapterLike = new BoostAdapter(ctx, userList);` in order to populate the listview with something, but apparently it's not enough. I've tried to leave the asynctask in the onCreate() and move `adapterLike = new BoostAdapter(ctx, userList);` in the onActivityCreated. But it returns the same error. 
Is something wrong with the AsyncTask code?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if your problem was solved , however , I had the same problem and bring the solution here :
the problem is that the main thread runs faster than the secondary thread (or asyncktask ), then we must ensure that when we make the list.setAdapter () our user list contains data.
For example , placing this line of code in the " onPostExecute " the AsyncTask . 
In your case:

```
onPostExecute(anyObject){
    adapterLike = new BoostAdapter(ctx, userList);
    listv.setAdapter(adapterLike);
}
```